# Find the sum of these definite integrals , same integrand different limits.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am required to find the following (Source is unknown):$$\int_{-5}^{-2} (\frac{x^2-x}{x^3-3x+1})^2 dx+\int_{\frac{1}{6}}^{\frac{1}{3}} (\frac{x^2-x}{x^3-3x+1})^2 dx+\int_{\frac{6}{5}}^{\frac{3}{2}} (\frac{x^2-x}{x^3-3x+1})^2 dx$$

Initial thoughts:

The integrands are same but with different limits. The limits  are related to each other in a very noticeable way, however I am not able to exploit his. Like: $-1* \frac{1}{-2} (\text{reciprocal of the limit of the first integral})* \frac{1}{\frac{1}{3}}(\text{reciprocal of the limit of the second integral}) = \frac{3}{2}(\text{ limit of the third integral})$,

Some tries:

Tried to solve: $\int (\frac{x^2-x}{x^3-3x+1})^2 dx$

$x^3-3x+1$ invites a substitution  like $x=2\cos{t}$, since it could be expressed as $\cos{3t}$. However I felt it was of no use. Wolfram couldn't integrate it in terms of elementary functions which suggests, this probably has something to do with definite integral properties, and some clever trick which I am not able to find.

Maybe the integrand  is of the form $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{f(x)}{x^3-3x+1})$ for some $f(x)$ but I was unsuccessful in finding such a $f(x)$ either.

For  $\int_{\frac{1}{6}}^{\frac{1}{3}} (\frac{x^2-x}{x^3-3x+1})^2 dx$ I tried things like $x \to \frac{1}{t}$ but it didnt really budge. I could change all the limits of the integrals to $0$ and $1$, however the difference of the upper and lower limits for each of the integrals dont really look nice either.

Comment: I'm quite sure that the integral of nonnegative function is not $-\frac{2}{27}$; in fact it seems You skipped quite a big part of the Wolfram's answer

Comment: @WhamBangShang-a-Lang   Extremely sorry. Ill cut the part out.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about. Integral calculator here: https://mathdf.com/int/ provides a step-by-step solution for each of the integrals, but it looks terrible and clearly not a proper approach. I'll just throw in the observation that not only the limits multiply to $-1$ (as You've pointed out), but also the roots of the polynomial in the denominator

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3104918/evaluating-int-5-2-fx-dx-int-1-61-3fx-dx-int-6-53-2?noredirect=1

Comment: @Accelerator Thank you. So the correct idea was to try to convert to a single limit. I'm new to stackexchange, could you tell me exactly how to search for questions?

Comment: I use [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/). It works most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

*Just for the fun*

The antiderivative is not so complicated and does not require any change of variable.

Write
$$\frac{x^2-x}{x^3-3 x+1}=\frac{x(x-1)}{(x-a) (x-b) (x-c)}$$ where
$$a=2 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{9}\right) \qquad \qquad b=2 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{18}\right)\qquad\qquad c=-2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)$$ are the roots of the denominator.

Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{x^2-x}{x^3-3 x+1}=\frac A{x-a}+\frac B{x-b}+\frac C{x-c}$$ where
$$A=\frac{(a-1) a}{(a-b) (a-c)}\qquad B=\frac{(b-1) b}{(b-a) (b-c)} \qquad C=\frac{(c-1) c}{(c-a) (c-b)}$$

Squaring, the integrand is
$$\frac{\left(x^2-x\right)^2}{\left(x^3-3 x+1\right)^2}=\frac{A^2}{(x-a)^2}+\frac{B^2}{(x-b)^2}+\frac{C^2}{(x-c)^2}+$$
$$\frac{2 A B}{(x-a) (x-b)}+\frac{2 A C}{(x-a)
   (x-c)}+\frac{2 B C}{(x-b) (x-c)}$$ We  use again partial fraction decomposition for the last three pieces.
Integrating termwise
$$\int\frac{\left(x^2-x\right)^2}{\left(x^3-3 x+1\right)^2}\,dx=\frac{A^2}{a-x}+\frac{B^2}{b-x}+\frac{C^2}{c-x}+$$ $$\frac{2 A  (a (B+C)-b C-B
   c)}{(a-b) (a-c)}\,\log (a-x)+$$ $$\frac{2 B (C (a-b)+A
   (c-b))}{(a-b) (b-c)}\, \log (b-x)+$$ $$\frac{2 C  (B (a-c)+A   (b-c))}{(a-c) (c-b)}\,\log (c-x)$$

Now, tedious calculations and simplifications to arrive at a total of $\frac{624}{109}$ as given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3104918/evaluating-int-5-2-fx-dx-int-1-61-3fx-dx-int-6-53-2?noredirect=1).